# Given a group of 300 people, each student is a friend with exactly 200 other people.

Tags: graph-theory

Given a group of 300 people, each student is a friend with exactly 200 other people. (Nobody is his or her own friend, and if A is B’s friend, then B is A’s friend.) No four people are all friends with each other. Show how it is possible to find a group of 100 people among them in which no two people are friends?

Answer (score 0):

The following diagram is a hint ?

[image]

Comment: I see how this diagram suggests a friendship graph that meets the given conditions. However I don't see how this diagram generically represents _any_ friendship graph that meets the given conditions. My interpretation of the question is that _any_ friendship graph that meets the given conditions should be shown to have a subgraph of 100 singletons.